# bash arithmetic operation in csv file

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have some csv files and I need to sum 12% in 4th and 5th columns:

original file:

```
Destination,First Interval,Next Interval,First Price,Next Price
93,180,180,4.32210,4.32210,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#12.97&#30%
9370,180,180,4.50000,4.50000,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#13.50&#30%
9371,180,180,4.50000,4.50000,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#13.50&#30%
9372,180,180,4.50000,4.50000,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#13.50&#30%
```

desired output:

```
Destination,First Interval,Next Interval,First Price,Next Price,Formula
93,180,180,4.84075,4.84075,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#12.97&#30%
9370,180,180,5.04000,5.04000,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#13.50&#30%
9371,180,180,5.04000,5.04000,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#13.50&#30%
9372,180,180,5.04000,5.04000,ADD=#60:50&0|SEQ=intNxN@priceN&#13.50&#30%
```

any suggestions to do this via awk or sed

Comment: search the best way to do this, +200 files need to be changed and it's not easy to do in spreadsheet processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try the below awk command,

```
awk -F',' -v OFS="," '{$4=$4+((12/100)*$4);$5=$5+((12/100)*$5);}1' file
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/fvLNVt)

Answer (score 1):

This could be another option using `sed` and `awk`

```
sed 's/,/\t/g' file | awk '{print $4+((12/100)*$4), "\t", $5+((12/100)*$5)}'
```